# Как сделать картинка на одном уровне?

Tags: html, css

CSS:

```
.dish_1 {
    text-align: left;
}

.dish_2 {
    text-align: center;
}

.dish_3 {
    text-align: right;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="dish_all">
            <div class="dish_1">
            <img src="images/dish_1.png">
            <br>
            <a>КТО</a>
            </br>
            </div>
            <div class="dish_2">
            <img src="images/dish_2.png">
            <br>
            <a>КТО</a>
            </br>
            </div>
            <div class="dish_3">
            <img src="images/dish_3.png">
            <br>
            <a>КТО</a>
            </br>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Либо добавить float: left, либо через флексбокс, либо через display: inline-block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`display: flex`:

```css
.dish_all {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="dish_all">
  <div class="dish_1">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
    <br>
    <a>КТО</a>
    <br>
  </div>
  <div class="dish_2">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
    <br>
    <a>КТО</a>
    <br>
  </div>
  <div class="dish_3">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
    <br>
    <a>КТО</a>
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
```

`float: left`:

```css
.dish_all>div {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dish_all">
  <div class="dish_1">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
    <br>
    <a>КТО</a>
    <br>
  </div>
  <div class="dish_2">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
    <br>
    <a>КТО</a>
    <br>
  </div>
  <div class="dish_3">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
    <br>
    <a>КТО</a>
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
```

`display: inline-block`:

```css
.dish_all > div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
  text-align: left;
}

.dish_all {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="dish_all">
  <div class="dish_1">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
    <br>
    <a>КТО</a>
    <br>
  </div><!--
  --><div class="dish_2">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
    <br>
    <a>КТО</a>
    <br>
  </div><!--
  --><div class="dish_3">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
    <br>
    <a>КТО</a>
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.dish_all {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]